# Burninate [parameterized-types]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[parameterized-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameterized-types). No tag wiki. 31 question (all either on [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics), about generics but not tagged with them, or simply mis-tagged). I'd understand if it was a synonym for [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics), but it isn't even that!

I propose it is either made a synonym for [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics) or burninated.

Or maybe this term has some usage unrelated to generics that I am not aware of?